# VSCode: modify the regex to find filename+line-no in terminal panel

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever in the terminal panel there is a file name with a line number, there is an option (on Mac) to [command] + click it to open the file at that line.

so this works:

```
./myfile.txt:10
```

Now I have test output that uses a slightly different format;

```
./myfile.txt @ 10
```

And that doesn't work (only the filename is recognized, not the line number)

Is there a way to customize how those names+line numbers are matched? such that I can reconfgure it to also match on my test output?

Comment: read up on `problem matchers` in the task doc page

Comment: thx for the pointer @rioV8 but can you please shed a bit more light on the topic? The terminal problem matcher is an integrated one I assume? so how can I customize it

Comment: Would it be an option to post-process your command (e.g. using `grep`) to transform your output to the VS Code compatible format?

Comment: yes that thought crossed my mind, but I'd have to repeat it for each project where I use that test framework (Busted, for Lua language). I'd work but be cumbersome. Was hoping I could simply edit a regex somewhere and be done with it